# Object's property set to native function call, wrong practice?

Tags: javascript

Javascrip can have it's object's properties refer to functions, as shown in the example. Would this be considered wrong, as in "resource heavy" or in any other way cumbersome for the system:

```
var someGlobalVar = {
    someElement: document.getElementById("someElementsID")
};
```

It works, but I am wondering if it causes this call to be made every time the object is reference, or only at initialization, or when? Is it okay to write it like this?

Comment: In this case `someElement` refers to an DOM element (not to a function as you mentioned).

Comment: It referes to a native function call that returns a DOM element object.....but does it hurt the system, will it be "recalled" all the time I use this object or will it be set once and be done with it?

Comment: As every other expression - it is evaluated then the result of the evaluation is assigned to the lhs (receiver).

Comment: Do you not understand what I ask, is it evaluated EVERY time the object is called or only once?

Comment: I pretty much do. Please read my comment once again. I explicitly stated that the **RESULT OF EVALUATION** is assigned to lhs. PS: objects are not "called".

Comment: Again, WHEN is the result stored? Because if this was to be a non-native function it would be recalled every time the object's property is referred to, which would be very cumbersome for the system if this was to happen on lets say a thousand properties. PS: meant to say referred

Comment: I have explained everything in my comment above: 1. It is evaluated 2. The result of evaluation is assigned to the LHS. Please read more carefully. Thank you.

Comment: Read the answer below to see how to properly explain things, thanks for the effort

Comment: The answer below makes no sense. It does not explain nor prove when and how the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Is it incorrect, because it answers the question exactly as I asked it, I am not sure if it is a correct answer, but it does address the exact point I have an issue with here

Comment: It's not incorrect, but it does not clarify anything. But whatever - you are satisfied with it, so just accept it and have fun.

Comment: For me it clarifies it much better, because it has the aspect of time involved in it as well. Thanks for all the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if it causes this call to be made every time the object is reference

No, it doesn't.

> or only at initialization

Correct.

> Is it okay to write it like this?

Absolutely, provided the element will exist as of the time you create that object. (If it doesn't, `getElementById` will return `null`.)

This code:

```
var someGlobalVar = {
    someElement: document.getElementById("someElementsID")
};
```

...is handled like this if it's at global scope (from the name of the variable, I assume it is):

1. When the code is added to the global environment (e.g., by a `script` tag), a variable called `someGlobalVar` is created; it initially has the value `undefined`.
2. When step-by-step execution of that code starts (which is after all the `var` declarations and function declarations have been processed), the object initializer is processed like this:

   1. The object is created.
   2. The property initializer `someElement: document.getElementById("someElementsID")` is evaluated:

      1. The `document.getElementById("someElementsID")` part is evaluated and the *result* of that is the property value (an element reference, or `null`).
      2. The property is created on the object using the name `someElement` and the property value from the previous step.
   3. The object's reference is saved to the variable `someGlobalVar`.

Comment: Now if I wasn't to already accept the above as the proper answer, this would be the best way to answer this question. Thank you.

Comment: @Dellirium: Glad to help. JohnnyFaldo's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

```
var someGlobalVar = {
    someElement: document.getElementById("someElementsID")
};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var someGlobalVar = {
    someElement:null
};

someGlobalVar.someElement = document.getElementById("someElementsID");
```

Could also:

```
var someGlobalVar = {

   someElement:null,

   setSomeElement:function(e) {
      this.someElement = e;
   } 

};

someGlobalVar.setSomeElement(document.getElementById("someElementsID"));
```

Comment: Thank you for a proper answer

Comment: No worries, @zerkms is correct though - by lhs he means left hand side, so in terms of your question: someElement = the result of document.getElementById(), rather than the function itself, hence why they are equivalent (getElementById() being the function)

Comment: There is one thing that his answer doesn't address and your does, and this is the "time" aspect of it, as well as the recall aspect of it. With what you said, it is abundantly clear that the expression will only be evaluated once, and never again, and it will be evaluated as soon as the object is instantiated, with his, "result of evaluation is asigned to the LHS" the questions of "when" and "how many times" are not answered. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: I am not saying it is wrong, it just leaves these 2 questions open, whereas the answer like this, clears any doubt